# Jsoup: How to select direct parents until the root without their siblings?

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup, parent

I'm trying to get all direct parents of element, but also I get their siblings.

For example, I have this DOM structure...

```
<div class="html">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body">
    <a href="seznam.cz">seznam</a>
    <h2>Foo</h2> 
    <a href="google.com">google</a> 
    <p>
      <img class="first">
    </p>
    <img class="second"> 
    <ol>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want get all direct parents of **img** element with class **first** until a **div** with class **html**.

I've tried using the following code

```
Element element = document.select("img").first();
Node root = element.root();
```

But in the root var I get whole DOM structure also with all siblings.

**UPDATE**

After this in root var I have the whole DOM structure again:

```
<div class="html">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body">
    <a href="seznam.cz">seznam</a>
    <h2>Foo</h2> 
    <a href="google.com">google</a> 
    <p>
      <img class="first">
    </p>
    <img class="second"> 
    <ol>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want something like this:

```
<div class="html">
  <div class="body"> 
    <p>
      <img class="first">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add more clearity in your question ?

Comment: I updated my question. It's more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in path only, use `Element.cssSelector()`

It gives you whole DOM path e.g. `html > body > img`

"Path" returned by *Darshit Chokshi* approach is not unique.

Comment: Thank you, this is it what I want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all get all elements with class name 'first' using,

```
Elements childs = document.getElementsByClass("first");
```

Now, iterate all child elements to get their parent elements using,

```
    for( Element child : childs){
      Elements parents = child.parents();
      for(Element parent: parents){
        System.out.println(parent.tagName());
      }
    }
```

Try this, Hope it will work for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your willingness, but _lukyer_ answer was more helpfull.